# Optimized "Multidimensional" Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures, multidimensional-array

From birth I've always been taught to avoid nested arrays like the plague for performance and internal data structure reasons.  So I'm trying to find a good solution for optimized multidimensional data structures in Ruby.

The typical solution would involve maybe using a 1D array and accessing each one by `x*width + y`.

Ruby has the ability to overload the `[]` operator, so perhaps a good solution would involve using `multi_dimensional_array[2,4]` or even use a splat to support arbitrary dimension amounts. (But really, I only need two dimensions)

Is there a library/gem already out there for this?  If not, what would the best way to go about writing this be?

My nested-array-lookups are **the** bottleneck right now of my rather computationally-intensive script, so this is something that is important and not a case of premature optimization.

If it helps, my script uses mostly random lookups and less traversals.

Comment: I think, this is not Ruby's problem. If you need to solve such tasks, you have better choose another language. And when Ruby is best language for task, such questions can not appear in it. Maybe Python can help.

Comment: @Nakilon This is not ruby's problem; I just would like a solution in Ruby.  Surely there has to be **some** better way that's out there than nested arrays?

Comment: Also, when you have problems with perfomance, while operating with a lot of arrays, make sure, that your script doesn't do too much internal *dup*s. Sometimes it's possible to use enumerator instead of array somewhere inside evaluations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [narray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/)

> NArray is an Numerical N-dimensional
>   Array class. Supported element types
>   are 1/2/4-byte Integer,
>   single/double-precision Real/Complex,
>   and Ruby Object. This extension
>   library incorporates fast calculation
>   and easy manipulation of large
>   numerical arrays into the Ruby
>   language. NArray has features similar
>   to NumPy, but NArray has vector and
>   matrix subclasses.

Comment: +1: For some reason, I thought that narray only handled numbers, rather than allowing ruby objects.

Answer (score 3):

You could inherit from `Array` and create your own class that emulated a multi-dimensional array (but was internally a simple 1-dimensional array).  You may see some speedup from it, but it's hard to say without writing the code both ways and profiling it.

You may also want to experiment with the [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/) class.

All that aside, your nested array lookups might not be the real bottleneck that they appear to be.  On several occasions, I have had the same problem and then later found out that re-writing some of my logic cleared up the bottleneck.  It's more than just speeding up the nested lookups, it's about minimizing the number of lookups needed.  Each "random access" in an `n`-dimensional array takes `n` lookups (one per nested array level).  You can reduce this by iterating through the dimensions using code like:

```
array.each {|x|
    x.each {|y|
        y.each {|z|
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to do a single lookup in the first dimension and then access everything "behind" it, then a single lookup in the second dimension, etc etc.  This will result in significantly fewer lookups than randomly accessing elements.

If you need random element access, you may want to try using a hash instead.  You can take the array indices, concatenate them together as a string, and use that as the hash key (for example, `array[12][0][3]` becomes `hash['0012_0000_0003']`).  This may result in faster "random access" times, but you'd want to profile it to know for certain.

Any chance you can post some of your problematic code?  Knowing the problem code will make it easier for us to recommend a solution.

Comment: The problem is somewhat spread over a series of files; I was just wondering if there was a general solution for multidimensional arrays.  Thanks for your suggestions, though.  I'll look into seeing how they help.

Comment: If the data type that you are storing in the array is not a simple data type that can be used with the `NArray` class, you can also keep your objects in a normal, 1-dimensional array and use a multi-dimensional `NArray` to store the *index* of the associated object.  That way, you can balance the fast lookups of simple data types in an `NArray` while only having to do a single array lookup for whatever data type you are storing.

Answer (score 2):

nested arrays aren't that bad if you traverse them properly this means first traverse rows and then travers through columns. This should be quite fast. If you need a certain element often you should store the value in a variable. Otherwise you're jumping around in the memory and this leads to a bad performance.

Big Rule: Don't jump around in your nested array try to traverse it linear from row to row.